# Does blocking notifications at the system level stop data usage?

Tags: notifications, mobile-data

If I go to

```
Settings -> Apps & notifications -> Instagram (or some other app)
```

and turn notifications off for that app, does that stop data usage on my data plan?  I ask because the message, when you turn notifications off for an app, is

> At your request, Android is blocking this app's notifications from
>   appearing on this device

which would seem to imply that the Android OS will receive the notification, and swallow it up at the OS level.  Which would imply that the phone does receive the notification from the network, thus some data usage would occur against your data plan.

So does blocking notifications stop data usage, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So does blocking notifications stop data usage, or not?

It does not. A notification as stated in [Notifications Overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications) is simply:

> a message that Android displays outside your app's UI to provide the user with reminders, communication from other people, or other timely information from your app

When you are connected, your apps will connect to servers to receive messages and communicate them to you. Blocking the notifications does not block the apps from receiving the messages, but from showing them to you.